# Changing Workbook Reference with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, variables, reference

Currently, I have a workbook without VBA, that pulls the maximum value from a specific range on a few different sheets in an external workbook. In the future, I would like to be able to frequently update the source workbook, while the sheet name and cell ranges will always be the same. For example, the following are a few of my current cell formulas:

```
=MAX(ABS(IF('[Test.xlsx]Page_3'!$B$6:$B$107<$B$8,'[Test.xlsx]Page_3'!$A$6:$A$107)))
=MAX(ABS(IF('[Test.xlsx]Page_4'!$B$6:$B$107<$B$8,'[Test.xlsx]Page_4'!$A$6:$A$107)))
```

Is there a way that I can define a sheet name, while still using these formulas in the cells? What I am envisioning is something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim path As String
Dim wbk As Workbook

path = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path)


End Sub
```

then I would be able to use that variable within the cells like this:

```
=MAX(ABS(IF('[wkb]Page_3'!$B$6:$B$107<$B$8,'[wkb]Page_3'!$A$6:$A$107)))
```

Is something like this possible? I would like to avoid coding all of my functions within the VBA window. I am much more comfortable with the syntax of the Excel functions.

Comment: You can do this without vba via edit links, change source.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you for the reply. This is exactly what I needed to do and much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testOpenWB_Formula()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, path As String, wbk As Workbook, shortName As String

  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  path = Application.GetOpenFilename()
  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path)

   shortName = Split(path, "\")(UBound(Split(path, "\")))

  sh.Range("A8").Formula = "=MAX(ABS(IF('[" & shortName & "]Page_3'!$B$6:$B$107<$B$8,'[" & _
                                                        shortName & "]Page_3'!$A$6:$A$107)))"
  sh.Range("A9").Formula = "=MAX(ABS(IF('[" & shortName & "]Page_4'!$B$6:$B$107<$B$8,'[" & _
                                                        shortName & "]Page_4'!$A$6:$A$107)))"
End Sub
```

Take care to change the cells where the formulas to be placed ("A8" and "A9" in my test code).

Comment: @user14185499: Did you find some time to test the above solution?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will keep it in mind for the future but in this case, I really need the formulas to be written in the cells as other people who haven't used VBA may be using the workbook. As someone mentioned above, I can actually do this much simpler with edit links, change source. Again, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user14185499: My code only answered your question as it is formulated... And automatically change the formulas as requested. If it looks more convenient to  manually edit links, no problem with me.